# root user execution fails

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

When I run `python abc.py` it runs fine

But when I do sudo `python abc.py` then it shows some packages missing error. Of the several import errors, here's the one:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Why?

What I think is that those packages are installed with normal user(ubuntu) permissions and not root permissions. If this is the case, how should I get over with this? Do I have to install all the packages again with root access?

Note: everything I discussed here is w.r.t ec2 linux ubuntu machine

Comment: What do you mean by "Installed with normal user permissions"? How did you install the package? You should either install it via Ubuntu's package manager (`apt-get`) or via easy_install or pip as root.

Comment: I installed packages using `pip install package-name` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The sudo environment may not contain your `PYTHONPATH`

`/etc/sudoers` contains Defaults `env_reset`.
Simply add Defaults `env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"` to `/etc/sudoers` and it will work just fine with `sudo`.

Comment: it says `W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file` 
will that not cause any problem?

Comment: read this - how to edit sudoers: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos

Comment: this is not working for me, when i do echo $PYTHONPATH this is giving me no output - `BLANK`

Comment: python on the system was installed using Anaconda in the system

Comment: Try this: add export `PYTHONPATH=/your/custom/path` to `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`. add `PYTHONPATH` to `Defaults env_keep += "ENV1 ENV2 ..."` in sudoers file. remove Defaults `!env_reset` from sudoers file if present